# markers places are incorrect in KML google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I made a map on Google Maps, I downloaded  the  KML  file  and  used  it  in  a map with sidebar.  But  the  places  of  the markers  are incorrect. All of  them are  below the correct places. The code  is  as below. Example page is on [test page](http://www.siterary.com/0test.html) .If I use the simple KML layer example of Google, same errors occur.

```
<style type="text/css">
 html, body, #map_canvas {
width:   750px;
height:  600px;
margin:  0;
padding: 0;
}
.infowindow * {font-size: 90%; margin: 0}
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ProjectedOverlay.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var geoXml = null;
var geoXmlDoc = null;
var map = null;
var myLatLng = null;
var myGeoXml3Zoom = true;
var sidebarHtml = "";
var infowindow = null;
var kmlLayer = null;
var filename = "europeancapitals.xml";
  function MapTypeId2UrlValue(maptype) {
    var urlValue = 'm';
    switch(maptype){
      case google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID:    urlValue='h';
                        break;
      case google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE: urlValue='k';
                        break;
      case google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN:   urlValue='t';
                        break;
      default:
      case google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP:   urlValue='m';
                        break;
    }
    return urlValue;
  }

      // ========== This function will create the "link to this page"
      function makeLink() {
//        var a="http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktothis.html"
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var a = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
           + "?lat=" + map.getCenter().lat().toFixed(6)
           + "&lng=" + map.getCenter().lng().toFixed(6)
           + "&zoom=" + map.getZoom()
           + "&type=" + MapTypeId2UrlValue(map.getMapTypeId());
        if (filename != "europeancapitals.xml") a += "&filename="+filename;
        document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = '<a href="' +a+ '">Link to this page<\/a>';
      }
    function initialize() {
      myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(46,14);
      // these set the initial center, zoom and maptype for the map 
      // if it is not specified in the query string
      var lat = 46;
      var lng = 14;
      var zoom = 8;
      var maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;

      // If there are any parameters at eh end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
      // looking something like  "?marker=3"

      // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
      var query = location.search.substring(1);

      // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
      var pairs = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
        // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
    var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1).toLowerCase();

        // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
        if (argname == "id") {id = unescape(value);}
        if (argname == "filename") {filename = unescape(value);}
        if (argname == "marker") {index = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "lat") {lat = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "lng") {lng = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "zoom") {
      zoom = parseInt(value);
      myGeoXml3Zoom = false;
    }
        if (argname == "type") {
// from the v3 documentation 8/24/2010
// HYBRID This map type displays a transparent layer of major streets on satellite images. 
// ROADMAP This map type displays a normal street map. 
// SATELLITE This map type displays satellite images. 
// TERRAIN This map type displays maps with physical features such as terrain and vegetation. 
          if (value == "m") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;}
          if (value == "k") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;}
          if (value == "h") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;}
          if (value == "t") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;}

        }
      }
      if (!isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lng)) {
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      }
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: zoom,
                    center: myLatLng,
                    // zoom: 5,
                    // center: myLatlng,
                    mapTypeId: maptype
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                      myOptions);
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

   geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
                    map: map,
                    infoWindow: infowindow,
                    singleInfoWindow: true,
            zoom: myGeoXml3Zoom,
            markerOptions: {optimized: false},
                    afterParse: useTheData
                });
                geoXml.parse(filename);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", makeSidebar);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "center_changed", makeSidebar);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", makeSidebar);
      // Make the link the first time when the page opens
      makeLink();

      // Make the link again whenever the map changes
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'maptypeid_changed', makeLink);
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', makeLink);
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', makeLink);
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', makeLink);
            };

function kmlPgClick(pm) {
   if (geoXml.docs[0].placemarks[pm].polygon.getMap()) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon,"click");
   } else {
      geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon.setMap(map);
      google.maps.event.trigger(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon,"click");
   }
}
function kmlPlClick(pm) {
   if (geoXml.docs[0].placemarks[pm].polyline.getMap()) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polyline,"click");
   } else {
      geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polyline.setMap(map);
      google.maps.event.trigger(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polyline,"click");
   }
}
function kmlClick(pm) {
   if (geoXml.docs[0].placemarks[pm].marker.getMap()) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(geoXml.docs[0].placemarks[pm].marker,"click");
   } else {
      geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].marker.setMap(map);
      google.maps.event.trigger(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].marker,"click");
   }
}
function kmlShowPlacemark(pm) {
  if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon) {
    map.fitBounds(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polygon.bounds);
  } else if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polyline) {
    map.fitBounds(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].polyline.bounds);
  } else if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].marker) {
    map.setCenter(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[pm].marker.getPosition());
  } 

   for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length;i++) {
     var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
     if (i == pm) {
       if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setMap(map);
       if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setMap(map);
       if (placemark.marker) placemark.marker.setMap(map);
     } else {
       if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setMap(null);
       if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setMap(null);
       if (placemark.marker) placemark.marker.setMap(null);
     }
   }
}

var highlightOptions = {fillColor: "#FFFF00", strokeColor: "#000000", fillOpacity: 0.9, strokeWidth: 10};
var highlightLineOptions = {strokeColor: "#FFFF00", strokeWidth: 10};
function kmlHighlightPoly(pm) {
   for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length;i++) {
     var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
     if (i == pm) {
       if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setOptions(highlightOptions);
       if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setOptions(highlightLineOptions);
     } else {
       if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setOptions(placemark.polygon.normalStyle);
       if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setOptions(placemark.polyline.normalStyle);
     }
   }
}
function kmlUnHighlightPoly(pm) {
   for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length;i++) {
     if (i == pm) {
       var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
       if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setOptions(placemark.polygon.normalStyle);
       if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setOptions(placemark.polyline.normalStyle);
     }
   }
}


function showAll() {
   map.fitBounds(geoXmlDoc.bounds);
   for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length;i++) {
     var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
     if (placemark.polygon) placemark.polygon.setMap(map);
     if (placemark.polyline) placemark.polyline.setMap(map);
     if (placemark.marker) placemark.marker.setMap(map);
   }
}

function highlightPoly(poly, polynum) {
  //    poly.setOptions({fillColor: "#0000FF", strokeColor: "#0000FF", fillOpacity: 0.3}) ;
  google.maps.event.addListener(poly,"mouseover",function() {
    var rowElem = document.getElementById('row'+polynum);
    if (rowElem) rowElem.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFA5E";
    if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[polynum].polygon) {
      poly.setOptions(highlightOptions);
    } else if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[polynum].polyline) {
      poly.setOptions(highlightLineOptions);
    }
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(poly,"mouseout",function() {
    var rowElem = document.getElementById('row'+polynum);
    if (rowElem) rowElem.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    poly.setOptions(poly.normalStyle);
  });
}  

// == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==
function makeSidebarPolygonEntry(i) {
  var name = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].name;
   if (!name  || (name.length == 0)) name = "polygon #"+i;
   // alert(name);
   sidebarHtml += '<tr id="row'+i+'"><td onmouseover="kmlHighlightPoly('+i+');" onmouseout="kmlUnHighlightPoly('+i+');"><a href="javascript:kmlPgClick('+i+');">'+name+'</a> - <a href="javascript:kmlShowPlacemark('+i+');">show</a></td></tr>';

}
function makeSidebarPolylineEntry(i) {
  var name = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].name;
   if (!name  || (name.length == 0)) name = "polyline #"+i;
   // alert(name);
   sidebarHtml += '<tr id="row'+i+'"><td onmouseover="kmlHighlightPoly('+i+');" onmouseout="kmlUnHighlightPoly('+i+');"><a href="javascript:kmlPlClick('+i+');">'+name+'</a> - <a href="javascript:kmlShowPlacemark('+i+');">show</a></td></tr>';

}
function makeSidebarEntry(i) {
  var name = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].name;
   if (!name  || (name.length == 0)) name = "marker #"+i;
   // alert(name);
   sidebarHtml += '<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><a href="javascript:kmlClick('+i+');">'+name+'</a></td></tr>';
}

function makeSidebar() {
  sidebarHtml = '<table><tr><td><a href="javascript:showAll();">Show All</a></td></tr>';
  var currentBounds = map.getBounds();
// if bounds not yet available, just use the empty bounds object;
if (!currentBounds) currentBounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
if (geoXmlDoc) {
  for (var i=0; i<geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length; i++) {
    if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].polygon) {
      if (currentBounds.intersects(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].polygon.bounds)) {
         makeSidebarPolygonEntry(i);
      }
    }
    if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].polyline) {
      if (currentBounds.intersects(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].polyline.bounds)) {
         makeSidebarPolylineEntry(i);
      }
    }
    if (geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].marker) {
      if (currentBounds.contains(geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i].marker.getPosition())) {
         makeSidebarEntry(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
  sidebarHtml += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("sidebar").innerHTML = sidebarHtml;
}

function useTheData(doc){
  var currentBounds = map.getBounds();
  if (!currentBounds) currentBounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // Geodata handling goes here, using JSON properties of the doc object
  sidebarHtml = '<table><tr><td><a href="javascript:showAll();">Show All</a></td></tr>';
//  var sidebarHtml = '<table>';
  geoXmlDoc = doc[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length; i++) {
    // console.log(doc[0].markers[i].title);
    var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
    if (placemark.polygon) {
      if (currentBounds.intersects(placemark.polygon.bounds)) {
        makeSidebarPolygonEntry(i);
      }
      var normalStyle = {
          strokeColor: placemark.polygon.get('strokeColor'),
          strokeWeight: placemark.polygon.get('strokeWeight'),
          strokeOpacity: placemark.polygon.get('strokeOpacity'),
          fillColor: placemark.polygon.get('fillColor'),
          fillOpacity: placemark.polygon.get('fillOpacity')
          };
      placemark.polygon.normalStyle = normalStyle;

      highlightPoly(placemark.polygon, i);
    }
    if (placemark.polyline) {
      if (currentBounds.intersects(placemark.polyline.bounds)) {
         makeSidebarPolylineEntry(i);
      }
      var normalStyle = {
          strokeColor: placemark.polyline.get('strokeColor'),
          strokeWeight: placemark.polyline.get('strokeWeight'),
          strokeOpacity: placemark.polyline.get('strokeOpacity')
          };
      placemark.polyline.normalStyle = normalStyle;

      highlightPoly(placemark.polyline, i);
    }
    if (placemark.marker) {
      if (currentBounds.contains(placemark.marker.getPosition())) {
         makeSidebarEntry(i);
      }
    }

/*    doc[0].markers[i].setVisible(false); */
  }
  sidebarHtml += "</table>";
  document.getElementById("sidebar").innerHTML = sidebarHtml;
};


   function hide_kml(){

            geoXml.hideDocument();  

   }

   function unhide_kml(){

            geoXml.showDocument();  

   }
function reload_kml(){
   geoXml.hideDocument();
   delete geoXml;
   geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
                    map: map,
                    singleInfoWindow: true,
                    afterParse: useTheData
   });
   geoXml.parse(filename); 

}
   function hide_markers_kml(){
     for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.markers.length;i++) {
       geoXmlDoc.markers[i].setVisible(false);
     }
   }

   function unhide_markers_kml(){
     for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.markers.length;i++) {
       geoXmlDoc.markers[i].setVisible(true);
     }
   }
   function hide_polys_kml(){
     for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.gpolylines.length;i++) {
       geoXmlDoc.gpolylines[i].setMap(null);
     }
   }

   function unhide_polys_kml(){
     for (var i=0;i<geoXmlDoc.gpolylines.length;i++) {
       geoXmlDoc.gpolylines[i].setMap(map);
     }
   }
   function load_kmlLayer() {
     kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(filename);
     google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, "status_changed", function() {
       document.getElementById('kmlstatus').innerHTML = "Kml Status:"+kmlLayer.getStatus();
     });
     kmlLayer.setMap(map);
   }
   function hide_kmlLayer() {
     kmlLayer.setMap(null);
   }
   function show_kmlLayer() {
     kmlLayer.setMap(map);
   }

        </script>
    </head>
<body onload="initialize()">
        <h4>Reading a <a href="http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/kml/documentation/">KML</a> file with Google Maps JavaScript API <a href="http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/documentation/v3/">Version 3</a> and <a href="http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/">geoxml3</a>.</h4>
<!--  <button onclick="hide_polys_kml();">hide polylines</button>
  <button onclick="unhide_polys_kml();">unhide polylines</button> -->
  <button onclick="hide_kml();">hide</button>
  <button onclick="unhide_kml();">unhide</button>
  <button onclick="hide_markers_kml();">hide markers</button>
  <button onclick="unhide_markers_kml();">show markers</button>
  <button onclick="load_kmlLayer();">load kmlLayer</button>
  <button onclick="hide_kmlLayer();">hide kmlLayer</button>
  <button onclick="show_kmlLayer();">show kmlLayer</button>
<!--  <button onclick="reload_kml();">reload</button> -->
<table style="width:100%;"><tr><td>
        <div id="map_canvas">
        </div>
</td><td>
<div id="sidebar" style="width:300px;height:600px; overflow:auto"></div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">    <div id="link"></div></td></tr>
</table>
        <div id="map_text">
        </div>
<div id="kmlstatus"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the ["hotSpot"](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#hotspot) for your custom icons.

`<hotSpot x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction">`

> Specifies the position within the Icon that is "anchored" to the  specified in the Placemark. The x and y 
>   values can be specified in three different ways: as pixels ("pixels"), as fractions of the icon ("fraction"), or as 
>   inset pixels ("insetPixels"), which is an offset in pixels from the upper right corner of the icon. The x and y 
>   positions can be specified in different ways—for example, x can be in pixels and y can be a fraction. The origin of > the coordinate system is in the lower left corner of the icon.

The hotSpot tag is (now) supported (correctly) in the kmz branch of geoxml3:

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/europeancapitals_fixed.xml)